# How to check if data already exists on listview from database

Tags: vb.net

How to check if data already exists on listview from database?

```vb
Private Sub retrieve()
    Dim imglist As New ImageList
    imglist.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imglist
    ListView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 200)
    con.Close()
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    Dim strsql As String = "SELECT dbo.pictures.Nu_pic, dbo.FilePictures.Num_File, dbo.FilePictures.Num_pic, dbo.pictures.pic,dbo.Files.Num_file  FROM dbo.FilePictures INNER JOIN dbo.Files ON dbo.FilePictures.Num_File = dbo.Files.No_Genfile INNER JOIN  dbo.pictures ON dbo.FilePictures.Num_pic = dbo.pictures.Nu_pic where dbo.Files.Num_file=" & Text_NoFile.Text
    Dim dt_images As New DataTable
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = strsql
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
    adp.Fill(ds)
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim imb_buffer = CType(dr("pic"), Byte())
        Dim img_stream As New IO.MemoryStream(imb_buffer, True)
        img_stream.Write(imb_buffer, 0, imb_buffer.Length)
        imglist.Images.Add(dr("Nu_pic").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
        img_stream.Close()
        Dim lsvparent As New ListViewItem
        'lsvparent.Text = dr("pic").ToString
        lsvparent.ImageKey = dr("Nu_pic").ToString
        ListView1.Items.Add(lsvparent)
        lsvparent.Text = imglist.Images.Count.ToString
    Next
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be as simple as putting this in TextBox Text_NoFile: `1; DROP TABLE FilePictures; --`

Comment: @djv :-D good one!

Comment: Never concatenate strings to build CommandText. Always use parameters. I think djv showed what can happen if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of two following ways:

1. Use select distinct .... in the SQL statement.
2. Check the existence of row by key before adding listview.

Comment: i want to chick items in existanc on listview

Comment: What item key do you want to check the existence????

Comment: problem withe in the first its ok ...show images form database but in ths secand event when the press button again show images that before showed and new images...How to put condation read data in the first if existance not show again

Comment: how to cleare items before show images